# Problems cloning a git repository (Newbie problems)

Tags: git, ssh, msysgit, permission-denied, git-clone

Trying to set-up a git server on my local dev machine and have been following [this](http://www.timdavis.com.au/git/setting-up-a-msysgit-server-with-copssh-on-windows/comment-page-1/) website so far but am a little stuck when trying to clone a repository.

In git bash, here's my output:

```
$ git clone ssh://Administrator@192.168.2.10:4837/ssh/home/Administrator/project1.git
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Git/project1/.git/
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Any suggestions on why I would be getting a 'Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive)' error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're failing to authenticate with the git server.  Have you given it your public SSH key?

Comment: I've set-up copSSH on the server and so have the public keys for that, but how do I go applying these settings to git, as you say?

Comment: @Brett: you give your public key to the server and when you clone, you'll be prompted for the password/passphrase.  There should be a setting in the server itself (on github, it's in the user profile).